# Impossible calculated field

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have been trying for the past several hours to write a calculated field in Google Data Studio.

I need to know how to get a percentage calculation on some events. Table below:

```
|Event Label|Event Action    |Total Events|
|-----------|----------------|------------|
|CTA 1      |Link Displayed  | 100        |
|CTA 1      |Link Clicked    | 20         |
```

I want to get the conversion, which means dividing 20 by 100 but I can't seem to write a calculated which does that. I feel like I've tried everything e.g.:

```
sum((total events(link clicked)) / total events(link displayed)))
```

And the like. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

This function is not available yet through the data studio (note that data studio is brand new). For this you have to use the API which I would strongly recommend!

Here you could use r and the sqldf-package that would provide you the data as the data studio (very simple sql querys). The same package you have in phyton.